# How to rewrite main class as a Public Void method to be called from another class

Tags: java

I have written my program around the main **MonopolyGame.java** game class - however - I am adding features such as splash screens etc; and I would like to call each of these from a separate class **(RunFile.java)** . How do I rewrite the following part of my main class so that it can be called from the RunFile.java. When I try to do this I get the following error:

> The method MonopolyGame() is undefined for the type MonopolyGame

**MonopolyGame.java**

```
public class MonopolyGame extends JFrame{

// PRIVATE STATIC/DECLARATIONS ARE HERE

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

{
    //THIS IS WHERE I USED TO CALL THE SPLASH SCREEN

 // SplashScreen s = new SplashScreen(8000);
 // s.Splash();

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            try {
                MonopolyGame window = new MonopolyGame();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });


}}


  /**
  * Create the application.
  */
public MonopolyGame() 
{

    try {
        initialize();
          for(int i = 0; i < 41 ; i++)
          {
              properties[i]=new Props();
          }
          setProperties();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



public void initialize()  throws InterruptedException {
    //REST OF PROGRAM
```

**RunFile.java**

```
public class RunFile{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
SplashScreen s = new SplashScreen(8000);
s.Splash();

MonopolyGame m = new MonopolyGame();
m.MonopolyGame();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is remove `m.MonopolyGame()`. Since it has the same name as the class, it is a Constructor and so when you do `MonopolyGame m = new MonopolyGame();` it is running the logic inside of there so you don't need to do it again.

If you do want to call it separately, you should change the name of the method to something besides the classname (and add a return type such as void)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to rewrite the MonopolyGame() class, you can simply reflect the MonopolyGame() main method in your RunFile class.

```
public class RunFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName(MonopolyGame.class.getName());
        Method meth = aClass.getMethod("main", String[].class);
        meth.invoke(null, (Object) args);
    }
}
```